# How to insert a file into this code but not a string

Tags: unix

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
title='Unix Shell Programming'
read search_word
if [[ $title =~ $search_word ]]
then
   echo Yes - matchli
else
   echo No - match
enter code here
fi
```

I want to substitute the `$title` to a file called emplist. Is it possible? And how can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` like this:

```
if grep -q "$search_word" emplist
then
     # $search_word was found inside the file emplist
```

Comment: thank you for your help, and I want to ask one more question that could write like that:## if ! cut -c12-26 emplist | grep -q $name ##       and why I can't put [] outside like:                                             ## if [ ! cut -c12-26 emplist | grep -q $name ] ##

Comment: That's because `[` is actually a program (called `test`). Subsequent words are the arguments of `[` and are **not** evaluated as commands. To force evaluation by the shell, wrap the condition in backticks like so: ``if[ `...` ]``

Answer (score 1):

add these lines in your shell script,

```
echo "enter file name with extension"
read fname
cat $fname
```